# How do I compare the fields/properties between POCOs?

Tags: c#, generics, properties, comparison, poco

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing object properties in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp)

Let's say I have a POCO:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public IList<Person> Relatives { get; set; }
}
```

I want to compare two instances of Person to see if they're equal to each other. Naturally, I would compare `Name`, `DateOfBirth`, and the `Relatives` collection to see if they're equal. However, this would involve me overriding `Equals()` for each POCO and manually writing the comparison for each field.

My question is, how can I write a generic version of this so I don't have to do it for each POCO?

Comment: If you want to do that in a unit test and are using XUnit, there is a build in method for that:  Assert.Equivalent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not worried about performance, you could use reflection in a utility function to iterate over each field and compare their values.

```
using System; 
using System.Reflection; 


public static class ObjectHelper<t> 
{ 
    public static int Compare(T x, T y) 
    { 
        Type type = typeof(T); 
        var publicBinding = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public;
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(publicBinding); 
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(publicBinding); 
        int compareValue = 0; 


        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) 
        { 
            IComparable valx = property.GetValue(x, null) as IComparable; 
            if (valx == null) 
                continue; 
            object valy = property.GetValue(y, null); 
            compareValue = valx.CompareTo(valy); 
            if (compareValue != 0) 
                return compareValue; 
        } 
        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields) 
        { 
            IComparable valx = field.GetValue(x) as IComparable; 
            if (valx == null) 
                continue; 
            object valy = field.GetValue(y); 
            compareValue = valx.CompareTo(valy); 
            if (compareValue != 0) 
                return compareValue; 
        } 
    return compareValue; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I gave it a try,, but the `properties` and `fields` arrays are empty.

Comment: Found out why. Remove the publicBinding variable, or use some a different enum type than DeclaredOnly or Public.

Comment: The BindingFlags allow you to access any combination of fields, public or private or static, etc. I am sorry my defaults were not valid for you, but I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: You may also wish to ensure that null values are equal 

Replace: 
  `if (valx == null) 
     continue; 
  object valy = property.GetValue(y, null); `

With: 
  `object valy = property.GetValue(y, null);
  if (valx == null && valy == null) continue;
  if (valx == null) return -1;`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use reflection to do this in a general way, but it has performance and complexity drawbacks. It's much better to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` manually so that you get the results you expect.

See [Should I Overload == Operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640988/should-i-overload-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Implementing Equals() and GetHashCode() isn't much hassle.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj) return true;
    if (!(obj is Person)) return false;

    var other = (Person) obj;
    return this == other;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return base.GetHashCode();
}
```

See [Using Equals/GetHashCode Effectively](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2007/04/25/using-equals-gethashcode-effectively.aspx)

Comment: I'm confused. Your example is simply the default behavior of Equals(). And it may not be much hassle for one class but when you need to add in a bunch of boilerplate code to 50+ classes, it does become a hassle.